# Extract only DIGIT in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have string this, `Total Bill : $22.00`, I just want to extract 22 from this string, i'm confused how to get that, I have tried some code but it gives me 2200 rather than 22. My code is this,

```
 NSString * val = @"Total Bill : $22.00";
NSString *newString = [[val componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                       componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"VV %@",newString);
```

Comment: Do you always want the integer part? Or always trailing zeroes? What would you do with 24.30?

Comment: Why not get the substring between the `$` and the `.` ?

Comment: i want before decimal point value just. @kabanus

Comment: i want values without decimal point just. @rmaddy

Comment: May we have a _clear problem statement_ please? Give several sample inputs and the desired output for each.

Comment: Why not use `NSNumberFormatter` with decimal fraction digits set to 0.

Comment: how can i get the value 22 from my string just. @Brandon

Comment: @Nabeel; I added what I meant as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to find the location of the `$` and then return the rest of the string. This will give you the `22.00`.

```
NSString *val = @"Total Bill : $22.00";
NSRange dollar = [val rangeOfString:@"$"];
NSRange decimal = [val rangeOfString:@"."];
if (dollar.location != NSNotFound && decimal.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(dollar.location + 1, decimal.location - dollar.location - 1)
    NSString *amount = [val substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"VV %@",amount);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No dollar sign or decimal found");
}
```

Comment: i want before decimal point value. @rmaddy

Comment: @Nabeel. You mean integer only `22` and not `22.00` right?

Comment: code above works, to strip off decimals, just do : [amount integerValue] . Consider using rounding otherwise 22.99 will still be 22 .

Comment: @Nabeel I updated to give just the integer part.

Comment: It is showing error in this line  NSRange range = NSRangeMake(dollar.location + 1, decimal.location - dollar.location - 1) . @rmaddy

Comment: @Nabeel Sorry, typo. That should be `NSMakeRange`, not `NSRangeMake`. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot u saved my time :). @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `NSCharacterSet` union with the characters you want to keep (currency separator -- decimal point in your case).. then invert it. Split the string and then join it using this character set. Then you can use `NSNumberFormatter` to get the result..

```
NSString *stringToParse = @"Total Blah: $22.00";
NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
[characterSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".,"]];
stringToParse = [[stringToParse componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[characterSet invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setPartialStringValidationEnabled:YES];

NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[formatter numberFromString:stringToParse]];

NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: But the string isn't just `$22.01`. It's `Total Bill : $22.00`.

Comment: i want my string to get values. @Brandon

Comment: @Nabeel; @rmaddy; Updated the answer. I added comma and decimal as valid currency separators. You can actually get the current currency separator from `NSNumberFormatter` or `NSLocale` instead of adding it yourself.. but for simplicity sake, I added it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSScanner` to extract values like this from a string. 
Depending on the type you want, you can use `scanDouble:`, `scanInt:` or something else. Here's an example:

```
    NSString *myString = @"Total Bill : $22.00";

    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:myString];

    // Moves the scanner to the "$" character, then eats that character
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"$" intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanString:@"$" intoString:nil];

    // Here you have options, can scan as a double or an integer, or convert later.
    double val = 0;
    [scanner scanDouble:&val];
```